# Linq Query Passing Select Statement as a Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list that contains the names of controls on a form and I recurse thru that with a foreach.  In the foreach I marry up the data with the control it belongs in and I keep getting an error.  Basically the one list is being used to generate the select statement. Any Help is appreciated!

```cs
DatabaseField = item.DatabaseField.ToString();
DatabaseValue = SelectOutput.Select(item.DatabaseField).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you give more description about the List you have ?

Comment: Could you share more light on to your code?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
    public class DatabaseDetails
    {
        public string DatabaseField { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseValue { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DatabaseDetails> SelectOutput = new List<DatabaseDetails>();
            List<string> ControlsInView = new List<string>();
            ControlsInView.Add("txtName");
            ControlsInView.Add("txtPhone");
            ControlsInView.Add("txtAddress");
            ControlsInView.Add("txtPIN");
            SelectOutput.Add(new DatabaseDetails()
            {
                DatabaseField = "txtName",
                DatabaseValue = "Ramesh"
            });
            SelectOutput.Add(new DatabaseDetails()
            {
                DatabaseField = "txtPhone",
                DatabaseValue = "121212121"
            });
            SelectOutput.Add(new DatabaseDetails()
            {
                DatabaseField = "txtAddress",
                DatabaseValue = "XYZ"
            });
            SelectOutput.Add(new DatabaseDetails()
            {
                DatabaseField = "txtPIN",
                DatabaseValue = "10001"
            });
            SelectOutput.Add(new DatabaseDetails()
            {
                DatabaseField = "txtEmail",
                DatabaseValue = "ramesh@xyz.com"
            });
            foreach (string item in ControlsInView)
            {
                string DatabaseField = item.ToString();
                string DatabaseValue = SelectOutput.Where(x => x.DatabaseField == DatabaseField).Select(y=>y.DatabaseValue).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine(DatabaseField + " : " + DatabaseValue);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work.  What I am trying to get is something like this:              
         Select DatabaseField From DatabaseValue   and return the string.  Not sure if you can do that in Linq

Comment: Could you share more details about what you're trying to do?